# GSheet AppScript Get Suspended Users, move to another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am a newbee to appscript and trying to go through a Google-Sheet named "users" with its fileid being "123xyz456abc", which has the below data in two separate sheets

=====

Sheet 1 = ActiveUsers
DisplayName,emailaddress
XYZ,xyz@domain.com
ABC,abc@domain.com

=====

=====

Sheet 2 = ExitedUsers
DisplayName,emailaddress
123,123@domain.com
456,456@domain.com

=====

I would like to refer to the GSheet named "ActiveUsers", and specifically refer to the emailaddress, find out if that emailaddress is active in Google Workspace or not

Post verification, if emailaddress not found in Google Workspace or if emailaddress is suspended in Google Workspaace, do the below
a. move the entire row to another sheet within the same Master GoogleSheet file which is titled as "ExitedUsers"
b. Notify the other emailaddress (like notify@domain.com) for any modifications to the GSheet

Please let me know.

Trying to build a script that can achieve the above logic ....

Do not have a working script as I am a newbee

Comment: `find out if that emailaddress is active in Google Workspace or not` This a rather vague/ambiguous statement. Would you please edit the question to provide a more detailed, explanation about what is intended by statement.

Comment: `Do not have a working script as I am a newbee` I can understand why you might not have resolved the problem, but have you tried to write _anything_? Being a newbie is not a problem per se.

Comment: Would you please edit the question to include sample data as well as examples of expected outcomes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this resolve through the excellent [GAMADV-XTD3](https://github.com/taers232c/GAMADV-XTD3) tool

The way I did it with help from Ross of GAMADV-XTD3 was :

Master URL of Google Sheet = https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/123abc456xyz/edit#gid=0

Sheet1:ActiveUsers = https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/123abc456xyz/edit#gid=0

Sheet2:ExitedUsers = https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/123abc456xyz/edit#gid=1234567890

Code:

```
gam config csv_output_row_filter_mode anymatch csv_output_row_filter "'Valid:boolean:false','suspended:boolean:true'" csv_output_header_force "DisplayName,primaryEmail,AccountExists,Suspended" redirect csv - multiprocess todrive tduser <Email-Address-of-User-with-Access-To-Shared-Drive-Sheet> tdfileid <SHEET-URL> tdsheet id:<ID-of-Sheet2-ExitedUsers> tdupdatesheet tdretaintitle tdnotify true tdshare Notify.User01@domain.com reader tdshare Notify.User02@domain.com reader tdnobrowser csv gsheet <Email-Address-of-User-with-Access-To-Shared-Drive-Sheet> <SHEET-URL> id:0 gam user "~primaryEmail" print users fields primaryemail,suspended addcsvdata DisplayName "~DisplayName" showvalidcolumn
```

- This will copy all the rows of users who do not have a valid email address or have their accounts suspended in Google Workspace
- If email address is not found , then Sheet2-ExitedUsers with column heading of Valid will be false, Suspended = blanks
- If email address is suspended , then Sheet2-ExitedUsers with column heading of Valid will be True, Suspended = True
- It will also notify the users Notify.User01@domain.com and Notify.User02@domain.com when the command runs